# How to get Firebase Token in android activity?

Tags: android, firebase

I am using `setToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken())` code to get the token but I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzv;
```

### build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'net.bohush.geometricprogressview:geometricprogressview:1.1.1'
    implementation project(path: ':andoird-sdk')
    implementation project(path: ':opentok-android-sdk-2.16.3')

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The above code is my build.gradle. Help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: I don't know what it is

Comment: Did you use latest version of `gms:google-services`? can you share `build.gradle` files?

Comment: @javadroid I have edited my question. Please look into it

Comment: Have you implemented a service tag in the Manifest file? @deluxan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you need to use FirebaseMessagingService to get token .. you will get token into its own method**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
    public void onNewToken(final String token) {

/// you will get token here you 
    enter code here

}

}
```

Comment: Now I am having new error `error: cannot access zzbfm`

Answer (score 1):

First of all fix version of all `firebase` library to [latest version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
you cant mix versions <= 12 and versions >= 15 of Firebase libraries as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732704/cannot-access-zzbfm-class-file-zzbfm-not-found-firebase-android)

then check you have properly enable `Multidex` on your project. [Enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

then use `build -> clean` to cleanup your project and dependencies. 
and for using `token` use the way of [@sonali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59799002/how-to-get-firebase-token-in-android-activity/59799308#59799308):